# Why is it that when rishonim quote Talmud Yerushalmi they don't quote the daf?

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-yerushalmi

Why is it that when rishonim quote from the Talmud Yerushalmi they don't quote the daf?

Comment: Same reason for not quoting the daf in TB: there was no standard pagination.

Comment: Tosafos, for example, generally quotes the daf when quoting TB but not when quoting a TY.

Comment: *Tosafos* does not quote the page numbers, that was added by later printers.

Comment: Tosfos only references chapter names, or the beginnings or ends of them eg. בריש פירקין

Comment: Suggested edit: why is there standard pagination for Talmud Bavli and not Talmud Yerushalmi?

Comment: @yoseflavi When Tosfos existed (Medieval times), dafim weren’t “invented” yet. That only came with the printing press; the modern pagination follows the Vilna edition specifically, from the mid-18th century. Any daf references before would have been included by later printers. Ditto for Yerushalmi; that had a standard set much earlier, of Perek X Halacha X, though I’m not sure exactly how far back that one goes.

Comment: See Tosafos in Menachos 4b for an perplexing thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nowadays, the Talmud Bavli normally uses the printed edition of the Vilna Shas. Those who write translations or extra commentaries, will use the Vilna Shas pagination in order to keep the references standard. Those commentaries or references that came before the Vilna shas was printed can only point to the perek and mishna within the perek because the pagination had not yet been standardized. The Talmud Yerushalmi did not have a standard printed edition to refer to.